# JDO-GAE Key getting created even when IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY is commented

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following code,

```
public class UserAccount {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent
  private Long id;  
  ....
```

so, creating the primary key via code, but when I view the datastore viewer through

```
http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin , I see key got populated via datastore (some encoded key). Is this an expected behavior ?. The problem however is when I try to connect my child objects with the parent objects. Thanks alot.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's absolutely expected. For more info take a look at [JDO Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata#Keys)